# ввод номера телефона

Tags: android

мне надо преобразовать ввод номера. То есть если я ввожу номер 81234567891, чтобы он преобразовывался в +7 (123) 345-78-91. Я пробовал использовать плагин от github, но он не сработал. Так же на другом форуме нашел фрагмент кода ,но он так же не сработал, может есть какой-то фрагмент кода, который может помочь?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPhone"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:paddingLeft="67dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Телефон"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="11"
            />
```

Comment: По существу вопроса - есть [библиотека от роботов](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android) для этого

Comment: для тех кто пишет первую программу это не так легко, конечно кто уже обучился этому всему так и буду писать, что легко и элементарно, а кто только учится , спрашивают ,вроде для этого и созданы форумы

Comment: Артем, это понятно. Но как я понимаю, многие начинающие программисты, незнакомы с такой вещью, как алгоритм. И не пытаются сначала понять,как должна работать задача,а сразу хотят написать код. Ведь поняв алгоритм, уже понятно становится что писать. А там уже и как писать. И такие узкие решения, на основе что писать, уже описаны в интернете, что нет необходимости задавать вопросы.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что вам нужно: переформатировать введенный номер телефона в некий формат или же сделать маску ввода номера телефона? Алгоритм решения в обоих случаях совершенно разный.

Comment: @Артем конечно же не так легко. Но если ничего не писать самостоятельно, а все время искать код в интернете и просить у других, то никогда и не станет легко. Если сам ничего не будешь делать, то никогда ничему и не научишься.

Answer (score 1):

Задача распадается на 2 части:

1. Собственно парсинг введенного в свободном формате номера телефона на некий стандартизированный формат (в вашем случае на  `+7 (123) 345-78-91` - это т.н. международный формат). В общем случае это довольно сложная задача, поскольку в разных странах совершенно разные правила/умолчания по представлению телефонных номеров. Задача  решается гугловской библиотекой [libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber). Пример парсинга [номера 81961234567 здесь](https://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=89161234567&country=RU&geocodingLocale=ru), обратите внимание, что если вы попытаетесь [спарсить номер 81234567891](https://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=81234567891&country=RU&geocodingLocale=ru) (как в вашем случае, то либа поймет, что в России нет кода 123 и не спарсит его верно :)
2. Создание маски ввода номера телефона в этом самом международном формате, это уже проще задача. На гитхабе есть полно библиотек решающих эту задачу, [например](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/MaskedEditTextWatcher) или [здесь](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать эту библиотеку: [вот эту](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android)

*Установка*:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.redmadrobot:input-mask-android:6.0.0'
    
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$latest_version'
}
```

Далее в ваш `EditText` ставите это и всё:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789 -".
 ... />
```

Comment: Эммм, Вы так и не показали, как библиотеку использовать! Я конечно понимаю, что оно все в гите есть, но раз уж ответ пишете, то надо полностью!